# Append values from multiple yaml files that contain the same key to a list variable

Tags: json, linux, ansible

Multiple yaml files contain a value with key `id` that I need to append to a list variable.

```yaml
---
name: somename
group: somegroup
id: someid
```

I've tried using `ansible.builtin.command` to cat and register the contents of the files but have not been successful in finding a way to filter the `stdout_lines` returned to get to the value I'm after. My attempt looks something like the following but there's been so many iterations at this point that it's all a bit jumbled.

```yaml
- name: Store job definition content
  local_action:
    module: ansible.builtin.command
    cmd: "cat {{ item.path }}"
  loop:
    "{{ definition_files.files }}"
  register:
    job_definitions

- name: Get a list of existing jobs ids
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    existing_jobs: "{{ existing_jobs + (item.stdout | to_yaml | map(attribute='id')}}"
  loop:
    "{{ job_definitions.results }}"
```

Another example that's also incorrect and doesn't work but demonstrates what I've been messing around with to try to get my result:

```yaml
- name: Define empty list
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    uuid_list: []

- name: Create a list of job ids from template files
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    uuid_list: "{{uuid_list + lookup('file', item.path | to_yaml).id }}"
  loop:
    "{{ definition_files.files }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following test directory layout

```
.
├── definition_files
│   ├── def1.yaml
│   └── def2.yaml
└── test.yaml
```

Content of the test definition files

`definition_files/def1.yaml`

```yaml
name: name1
group: group1
id: abc
```

`definition_files/def2.yaml`

```yaml
name: name2
group: group2
id: def
```

The following `test.yaml` playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: append ids from each files
      set_fact:
        my_id_list: "{{ my_id_list | d([]) + [(lookup('file', item) | from_yaml).id] }}"
      loop: "{{ q('fileglob', 'definition_files/*.yaml' ) }}"

    - debug:
        var: my_id_list
```

Gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yaml 

PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [append ids from each files] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/definition_files/def2.yaml)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/definition_files/def1.yaml)

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_id_list": [
        "def",
        "abc"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Latest test was made with the following ansible version:

```
$ ansible-playbook --version
ansible-playbook [core 2.16.1]
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/home/user/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/user/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /home/user/.local/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] (/usr/bin/python3)
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
```

Comment: The first error I hit was FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ my_id_list | d([]) + [(lookup('file', item.path) | from_yaml).id] }}): can only concatenate str (not \"list\") to str"} I changed [(lookup('file', item) | from_yaml).id] to (lookup('file', item) | from_yaml).id and the error has now gone to FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'id'

Comment: interestingly, just to be sure there was nothing weird with my setup, I switched my python venv to one with the latest versions on PyPI, this includes all of the ansible executables and dependencies. When I do this, the error consistently goes to the second error FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'id'. When I switch back to my default venv the error consistently goes back to the first error about can only concatenate str not list to str.

Comment: @Arno Just to let you know that, a year after, this is still giving the exact expected result on my side. See edit with latest ansible version used. The only possible glitch I can think of on your side is if you already have something inside the `my_id_list` variable when you hit the above task.

Comment: I don't remember what I was working on when I asked this question but after being more immersed in Ansible the past while your answer also made sense right away, I append to list in that way regularly but didn't know about the short form of default or used query before but I'll keep them in mind, will come in handy.